# cascading use of MS TTS speakTextAsync() does not work synchronously

Tags: javascript, sdk, text-to-speech, azure-sdk

I use a browser javascript Speech SDK with cascading use of MS TTS speakTextAsync() :

I expected the text to be spoken in sync, but the phrases overlap each other.
I will be grateful for any hints ...

```
async function f(){
  await speechSynth.speakTextAsync("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  await speechSynth.speakTextAsync("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
  await speechSynth.speakTextAsync("A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
}
f();
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid overlapping the text to speech `await` keyword will makes the previous one to finish executing before starting. By that the phrases won't overlap each other.

- I installed `microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sd` package to use the Speech SDK.
- I used below code as per the given requirement.

```
const SpeechSDK = require("microsoft-cognitiveservices-speech-sdk");
const  app = express();

async  function  speakText(text) {

try {
const  speechConfig = SpeechConfig.fromSubscription("<subscription key>", "<location>");
const  synthesizer = new  SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);
await  synthesizer.speakTextAsync(text);
} 
catch (err) {
console.error(err);
}
}

  

async  function  speakMultipleTimes() {

//please add the speaktext requirement hear as per the requirement

}

app.get("/", async  function (req, res) {
await  speakMultipleTimes();
res.send("Speech generated successfully.");
});

  
const  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, function () {
console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}.`);

});
```

- The above code speaks the text synchronously and wait for each phrase before speaking the next one.

[image]

- I can hear the speech with generated response successfully.

[image]

Once refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-text-to-speech?tabs=windows%2Cterminal&pivots=programming-language-javascript) for better understanding.